# How to configure Jenkins to periodically run the same build with different parameters

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, build-automation

I have a Jenkins build that takes a parameter PLATFORM whose options are 32 and 64. I want to have a nightly build of both of these (eg: 32bit is built at 19:00 and 64 is done at 21:00).

Is there a way to configure the system to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as a matrix build.  You might not be able to schedule the builds separately.